# Create a new SessionID with Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have read this page about [chrome.sessions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sessions) and searched the web, but I cant find how I can change the sessionID or create a new one within a Chrome Extension.

Regards, Peter

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do this. A session is in my opinion started at the browser launch.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin You are correct, care to make that an answer?

Comment: Okay... And what about the Session Manager extension? As I read it, it saves sessionID, so if I could safe multiple ID's, I could switch back to them? This would be a workaround to 'change' the sessionID.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. A session is started at the browser launch.

Comment: If some one want more informations, I can edit and add some explanations. I don't have time today for it ;-)